# Telescope app not mobile responsive via the custom URL

Tags: ios, heroku, meteor, dns, telescope

I built a site to try out Telescope/meteor and deployed it with Heroku using a custom domain from Godaddy --->

*ISSUE*: When viewing the site iOS :

**Good** > responsive mobile version appears via the default Heroku url: unfair.herokuapp.com
**Bad** > mobile version does not appear via the custom url: www.un-fair.net (desktop 'full site' shows up)

I updated the 'ROOT_URL' in Heroku settings and switched it from the default URL to the custom URL but didn't fix the issue.

Any suggestions ?

Heroku support claims it is not an issue on their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to do, as mine is displaying all right via my Godaddy custom domain.

When setting up my custom domain with my Telescope app on Heroku, I needed to change the DNS settings via Godaddy. You'll need to add (or update if it's already there) a CNAME record where "Host" is "www" so that "Points To" is "unfair.herokuapp.com".

How to find the DNS manager in Godaddy: https://www.godaddy.com/help/access-the-dns-manager-19182

Comment: Thanks for the info and link. Cant wait to fix this.

Comment: Thanks again A Lin. That worked great. It was pointed to @ still.

Comment: @jerstin_stogi awesome! glad to hear it.

Comment: @jerstin_stogi Any chance I could get my answer officially accepted? :)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is an issue with your redirection. For example, if you're redirecting via an iFrame instead of setting the DNS, the iFrame hosted by GoDaddy might not have the proper meta tags required to enable the responsive version on mobile.

Comment: Thanks Sacha. I'll check it out again within GoDaddy.